# Why does logging a rejected `Promise` in Node 7.2.0 result in also logging a stack trace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, es6-promise

When running this code in Node 7.2.0:

```
let prms = Promise.reject(new Error('error'));
prms.catch(() => {});

console.log(prms);
```

I was expecting `Promise {<rejected> Error: error}` to be logged to the console but instead I receive this output:

```
Promise {
  <rejected> Error: error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/davidlund/Dropbox/test.js:1:89)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:535:3 }
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is the `.valueOf` representation of the Error:

```
> (new Error('error')).valueOf();
Error: error
    at repl:1:2
    at realRunInThisContextScript (vm.js:22:35)
    at sigintHandlersWrap (vm.js:98:12)
    at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:24:12)
    at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:313:29)
    at bound (domain.js:280:14)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:513:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

Compare:

```
function Foo() {

}

Foo.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return "FOOBAR"
}

let prms = Promise.reject(new Foo);
prms.catch(() => {});

console.log(prms); // Promise { <rejected> [String: 'FOOBAR'] }
```

Comment: But why is the `.valueOf` part being logged to the console. Is this something new in Node 7.2.0? - the output was different before I updated Node

Comment: @rabbitco `console.log` is not standardised, so it may output anything its developers want.